# Doorkeeper access token

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oauth-2.0, oauth-provider, doorkeeper

I'm trying to build up an OAuth2 provider with Doorkeeper and I wanted to test all existing flows, but got stuck at the first attempt.

I'm trying to test the authorization code flow. Everything works fine on getting the authorization code, but once I try to get the access token something gets wrong. Below mentioned are some of the steps.

```
      describe 'when sends an access token request' do

        let(:access_params) do
          { grant_type:  'authorization_code',
            code:         authorization_code,
            redirect_uri: application.redirect_uri }
        end

        let(:access_uri) { '/oauth/token' }

        before { page.driver.post access_uri, access_params }

        it 'returns valid json' do
          pp page.source
        end
```

I was expecting the json with the final access token, but I got this error. I checked out pretty well the client and the params. All seems fine to me.

```
        {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client authentication failed due to unknown client, no client authentication included, or unsupported authentication method."}
```

Can you help me on understanding what is missing?
Thanks

Comment: Any reason why you want to test these flows? OAuth flows are pretty well tested in doorkeeper

Comment: I know, I've been digging the code pretty well. Still I have to check those functionalities as some of my logics could broke them. I thing it's a good practice to build some integration tests for the main usage scenarios when you get an Engine which does pretty important things for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it work. I missed one important aspect about the OAuth2 specs, where the client must identify itself using basic auth. I solved adding it before the post, and it worked pretty well.

```
  before do
     page.driver.browser.authorize application.uid, application.secret
     page.driver.post access_uri, access_params
  end
```

Comment: hi, it been years. can i know where to add this code. since im new to ROR

Comment: @deanz you put that code inside your rspec test. 

describe '#index' do
          before do
          ...
          ...
          end
  end